# iOS: -[__NSCFString allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7976c750

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, crash, nsdictionary

Now I know this means it is trying to get all keys in a NSString, which isn't possible. However, I don't know why my dictionary is an NSString.

```
return [requestManager POST:@"/api/showData"
                           parameters:params
                              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                                  NSLog(@"the response object%@",responseObject);

                                  NSMutableArray *responseObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                                  for (NSDictionary *node in responseObject) {
                                      Model *data = [[Model alloc] initWithDictionary:node];
                                      [responseObjects addObject:data];
                                  }
                                  handler(YES,responseObjects);

                              } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                  handler(NO,nil);
                              }];
```

This code sends a request to the server and I get the following success response

> the response object{
>           "error_code" = 1;
>           message = "nothing found";
>           status = error;
>          }

In my initWithDictionary Method for my Model class this is what I have

```
   //Model Class
 - (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict{
      self = [super init];
      if (self) {
       NSLog(@"the dict is %@",dict);
      if ([[dict allKeys] containsObject:@"error_code"]) {

          }
         return self;
       }
```

The above line is what Is causing my problem. I logged the dictionary in this method and this is what I get

> "the dict is status"

Comment: You are not showing where `dict` is created and set to a value. Edit the question and add that to it.

Comment: I edited it, but it is created through the model class initwithdictionary.

Comment: The app simply crashes because you're not passing a dictionary but a string instead, check the JSON schema of the data you're getting from the backend.

Comment: The dictionary isn't an NSString.  The NSString is an NSString (apparently with the value "status"), but you've got its pointer in a variable that's typed as a pointer to a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check whether you're getting a dictionary or an array (that contains multiple dictionaries) as your responseObject,

```
return [requestManager POST:@"/api/showData"
                parameters:params
                   success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                       NSLog(@"the response object%@",responseObject);
                       NSMutableArray *responseObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                       if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                           Model *data = [[Model alloc] initWithDictionary:responseObject];
                           [responseObjects addObject:data];
                       } else if ([responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
                           for (NSDictionary *node in responseObject) {
                               Model *data = [[Model alloc] initWithDictionary:node];
                               [responseObjects addObject:data];
                           }
                       }
                       handler(YES,responseObjects);

                   } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                       handler(NO,nil);
                   }];
```